# C# I"m confused with this service routine

Tags: c#

So I am using C# with WinForms, My question is what is NewValue in this snippet? e is the event that has occured. So I'm telling the label vsliderecho's text to change to something.

```
private void V_Slider_Bar_scroll(object sender, SCrollEventArgs e)
{
    V_Slider_echo.Text= e.NewValue.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look up `ScrollEventArgs` in help, or msdn, then it lists the properties:

[`NewValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.newvalue.aspx) - Gets or sets the new Value of the scroll bar.

`ToString()` just gets the string value of the new value of the scroll bar, i.e  the numerical value of where the bar has moved to.

Answer (score 0):

[`NewValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.newvalue.aspx) is a property of [`ScrollEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.aspx), telling you the new value of the scrollbar.

`e` isn't the event itself - it's the *argument* associated with the occurrence of the event, i.e. the information about what's changed in terms of scrolling.

Your event handler just shows the user what the new value of the scrollbar is, basically.

Comment: It should be noted that sometimes the state of a control / property at the time of an event is not always well documented in MSDN. Usually a "changed" events occurs after the property has been assigned a new value, but in some cases it is not so trivial and sometimes there is no event when you expect it. E.g. if you assign null to the SelectedItem of a ComboBox, the change event is not raised.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly? It is an `int`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.newvalue.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [ScrollEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.aspx) contains information about the event that occured. The NewValue is the value that the scroll bar is currently located at.